# Java: constructor with one parameter; Error - Cannot find symbol - variable

Tags: java, constructor, runtime-error

I'm in Java programming (I'm on my first year at uni). I've got an assessment where I need to create 3 classes. In one of the classes I need to have a constructor with a parameter of String type. It needs to allow me to create a new object (pack of crisps) in which I am supposed to state the flavour of it.

Whenever I try to create the object I get the textbox where I can type in the flavour of crisps but when I press ok I get the error (e.g. ) Cannot find symbol - variable bbq.

I had a similar example before which took int type and it worked fine.

When I compare my code with other - working examples - I really can't find what I am doing wrong.

I would appreciate if someone could advise.

```
public class PackOfCrisps
{
private String flavour;
private int numOfCrisps;
private boolean open;

/**
 * Constructor for a single pack of crisps.
 */
public PackOfCrisps(String newFlavour)
{
    flavour = newFlavour;
    numOfCrisps = 10;
    open = true;
}

/**
 * Return whether the packet is empty.
 */
public boolean isEmpty() 
{
    if (numOfCrisps == 0) 
    {
        return true;
    } else
        return false;
}

/**
 * Return whether the packet is closed.
 */
public boolean isClosed() 
{
    return open;
}

/**
 * Change the boolean value of 'open' variable.
 */
public void open()
{
    open = !open;
}

/**
 * Return the flavour of the packet of crisps.
 */
public String getFlavour()
{
    return flavour;
}

/**
 * Decrease the number of crisps by 1 until the packet is empty.
 */
public void eatCrisps()
{
    if (open) 
    {
        System.out.println("Need to open the packet first!");
    } else if ((numOfCrisps > 1) && (numOfCrisps <= 10)){
        numOfCrisps = numOfCrisps - 1;

        System.out.println(numOfCrisps);
    } else {
        System.out.println("The packet is empty!");
    }
}
```

}

UPDATE

I'm using BlueJ for my programming. 
I would imagine that it must be something pretty 'simple' that I am missing because it is my 3rd week at university and we literally started from scratch.

UPDATE 2

I'm sorry if my answers don't always describe everything 100% but because I'm still a noob at programming I am bound to miss some info. I think this would be the answer to your question: because I use BlueJ, when I have a class in compiler (I believe displayed in a class diagram) I just right-click it and choose "new PackOfCrisps(String newFlavour)" and then I get the box in which I can type in crisps flavour but when I press 'Ok' I get error message.

[image: his is all I get/see]

I tried to play with other options to see if I can get any more info but with no success.

Comment: where is swing classes? how do you get textbox? command line?

Comment: +1 on your comment - hard to debug without seeing the usage.

Comment: You don't get the warning from *that* code, `bbq` appears nowhere. Also: `open()` is mis-named because it doesn't "open", it toggles the open state. Also: `public boolean isEmpty() { return numOfCrisps == 0 }`. Also: `if (open) { // need to open first }` makes zero sense.

Comment: how are you calling it

    PackOfCrisps bbq = new PackOfCrisps ("BBQ");   

?

Comment: You might want to add `this.flavour = newFlavour` just for clarity.

Comment: The source of error is not in the same PacketOfCrisps class. You need to provide code for all other components. Where do you see this error? On the console? In the browser? Are you using JavaScript? Are you using Swing or AWT or an applet?

Comment: You should mention how you are creating object. which would make me easy to help you...

Comment: Do you see a stacktrace (a list of lines containing files names, class names, method names and line numbers) when you get the error? If so then you should post the whole stacktrace.

Comment: Based on your update 2 here is my guess - the text box that BlueJ pops up probably allows you to type in a variable name or a string. If you want it to be a string then type in "BBQ" with the quotes. Without seeing more code, a stack trace, or using BlueJ myself it would be hard to know for sure though.

Comment: OMG. I knew it had to be something very 'simple'/silly! Lol. Thanks so much. I feel pretty stupid now :-P (Especially considering the fact I've spent a few hours thinking and googling what could have been wrong!)

Comment: Vetaxili: +1 for sticking with this question and providing updates to it as requested by the commentators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: This was a comment above, but I am "elevating" it to an answer.

Based on your Update 2 and the screenshots above here is my guess.

The text box that BlueJ pops up probably allows you to type in a variable name or a string. If you want it to be a string then type in "BBQ" with the quotes.

Answer (score -1):

Type bbq in quotes like this "bbq".
it will work